# process.env.REACT_APP_KEY not working with api calls

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, environment-variables

So far in 2 projects I created a .env file in the root of my project. I install npm install dotenv. I place (e.g.)`REACT_APP_KEY='123456'` in the env file .  In my `app.js` file I add `require("dotenv").config()`  in my component where I am making the api call i `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_KEY)` in the the console I get 123456. So far it looks like its working.  But when I place the `process.env.REACT_APP_KEY` in the api call I get 404 error?  What am i missing?  If I remove `process.env.REACT_APP_KEY` and add 123456, I get no error and the call works.  Is it because I am using `axios` to get the data, should i use `fetch`?  I can't seem to find anything that can help me with this.  I included my error below.
thank you.

```
xhr.js:177 GET https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=bali 401
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
getImages @ App.js:12
onSearchSubmit @ App.js:20
App @ App.js:22
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17811
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19049
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23940
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
(anonymous) @ index.js:7
./src/index.js @ index.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ reportWebVitals.js:14
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Comment: I figured it out ... my bad I'm still new and learning, I'm using upsplash api.  In my headers I had 
headers: {
    Authorization: `Client-ID process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESSKEY`,
  },
I changed it to 
headers: {
    Authorization: `Client-ID ${process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESSKEY}`,
  },
I don't know why I didn't realize I was calling a variable.

Comment: forgot the template literals in the object code
headers: { Authorization: \`Client-ID ${process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESSKEY}\`, },